# Link to "All sites" (https://stackexchange.com/sites) shows an error

Tags: bug, navigation

When navigating to `All sites` from main page or directly via https://stackexchange.com/sites in Chrome browser, there's an error page displayed with message:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Similarily, Firefox shows an error page with message:

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

Edit: this bug appears to apply for unauthenticated users only.

Comment: That is not what I get. The link works for me in both Chrome and Firefox, I'm on Windows 10, Can you check if maybe your ISP is playing tricks on your internet connection?